# Type inference issue using Pekko (Akka) AskPattern

Tags: scala, akka, scala-3

I am using the Ask pattern to implement simple RPC.

```scala
import org.apache.pekko.actor.typed.{ActorRef, Scheduler}
import org.apache.pekko.actor.typed.scaladsl.AskPattern.Askable
import org.apache.pekko.util.Timeout

import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future}

case class RequestMessage(replyTo: ActorRef[ReplyMessage])
case class ReplyMessage(ok: Boolean)

def Fails(handler: ActorRef[RequestMessage])(using ExecutionContext, Timeout, Scheduler): Future[Boolean] =
  handler.ask(rt => RequestMessage(rt)).map(_.ok)

def Ok(handler: ActorRef[RequestMessage])(using ExecutionContext, Timeout, Scheduler): Future[Boolean] =
  handler.ask[ReplyMessage](rt => RequestMessage(rt)).map(_.ok)
```

The function `Fails` gives this error:

```
value ok is not a member of Any
  handler.ask(rt => RequestMessage(rt)).map(_.ok)
```

The function `Ok` sets the type parameter for `ask` and does not give an error.

Why can't Scala 3 infer the correct return type for `ask`, and is there a cleaner way of working round this than explicitly naming the type?

Answer (score 0):

I think, that's because `ActorRef` is contra-variant: `ActorRef[Any]` is the "most specific" subclass matching the type, so it goes with it 
I don't think there is any cleaner way to use ask anti-pattern ... (some) people call it anti-pattern for a reason :)

Comment: I welcome any suggestions on how to improve/avoid usage of `ask`:) Also note that I have very similar code in Scala 2 that does not have this issue, so it does feel like something triggered by the new compiler.

Comment: Hm, yeah, I seem to remember there was some special handling of `Any` in scala 2 for similar situations ... I guess, they must have lost it in scala 3. As to replacement for `ask`, it is usually recommended to just `tell` both ways ...

Comment: @Tim FWIW doesn't seem to work [in scala2](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/rGKLJFQFRGqTcIJSj2mErA) either, albeit in a different way 

Comment: Ugh ... actually, never mind: [this](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/LSQM1AW4RtSoP0QqrSYe0w) _does_ work in scala 2